# Pythonic way of building a list by calling the last object in that list until it returns None

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a list of objects in Python. I have a starting object, called `foo`, which has a method on it called `GetParent()` that returns another object. What I'd like to do is continue calling `GetParent()` until it returns None, but keep track of a list any valid objects as I go.

The obvious way to do this seems to be something like this:

```
objects = list()
result = foo
while result:
    objects.append(result)
    result = result.GetParent()
```

For the sake of curiosity, is there any way you could do this in one or two lines in Python instead? Originally I figured something like sum/map/reduce could be abused to provide the desired behavior, but I'll be damned if I can figure it out since you need access to the last item of the list in order to call `GetParent()` again.

What's the most pythonic way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Define a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

```
def all_parents(obj):
    while obj:
        yield obj
        obj = obj.GetParent()
```

Then you can do:

```
objects = list(all_parents(foo))
```

You might actually want to make this a method in your class. Then you would call it as `foo.all_parents()`.